# Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' declared by the module

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I think I have looked through all the other questions with a similar title to this one but I have not found one that describes the same situation I am experiencing.

Environment: 
angular v4.4.4, 
angular-cli v1.4.4

I am getting this error quite often and initially I looked at all the other answers but none helped.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution turned out to be very simple.

Shutdown the angular-cli server and restart it (with ng serve).

So far that has worked every time for me.